# JavaScript Password Generator - Output

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, button

(I am new to programming)

The program: I have made a relatively simple JavaScript program, that generates a password when you click on a button.

The problem: Displaying the password with `document.write`, the whole page is overwritten, meaning that the button is removed and you have no opportunity to generate a new password. **Therefore**, I would like the password to go inside the paragraph with Id "pw".

Note that **document.write** is disabled in JSFiddle, so the result is set to display in console.
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3qh01ctp/1/

Thank you very much in advance, any help/advice appreciated!

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

function generate () {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    randomLetter = arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];
  console.log(randomLetter);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <button onclick="generate();">Generate password</button>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="pw">
    <!-- password should go here -->
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.write` is ancient and almost never used. Learn to use DOM-scripting instead.

Comment: Is this what's you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/75wmupch/ If so then I recommend looking up some basic javascript tutorials as those will cover the use of targeting DOM elements  such as `document.getElementById()`

Comment: Xufox, Utkanos, CBroe: Thank you for the suggestions very much, will definitely look into that.

@NewToJS: That is exactly what I was trying to do. I will have to do some more studying, thanks for the help AND the explanation

Comment: @thesystem You are very welcome, we all started somewhere. Plenty of research and small projects will help you learn and enable you to expand on your development. Just keep things small and simple to start with and it won't feel too much of a headache to learn. I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

function generate () {
  var randomLetter="";
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    randomLetter += arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];
    
  //console.log(randomLetter);
  }
document.getElementById("pw").innerText =randomLetter ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <button onclick="generate();">Generate password</button>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="pw">
    <!-- password should go here -->
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the innerHTML leaving it to only out put last result from the loop.

Comment: My bad, changed

Comment: Now `randomLetter` isn't defined. You must define it in the function but before the loop. I would recommend you define it with a empty value.

Comment: @NewToJS updated.... working fine...

Comment: This would be better if what currently is called `randomLetter` would have a better name. That variable holds the _whole password_, not one random letter.

Comment: yap i agree, something like `genpassword`. But i don't want make like i wrote new set of code...

Comment: @Kuru Thanks for showing how to code it, appreciate it

Comment: @Kuru I found your code to be the most useful, as you altered my code the least. However, I have one question. Is it not possible to assign randomLetter (the password) to "pw" without making randomLetter an empty string within the code? It seems a little confusing to me

Comment: you need to make a empty string, because at start we don't have any value for "randomLetter ", that mean the variable is declared but not initialized and we can't use variable in a calculation without initializing it, it will raise error. In this code`randomLetter += arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];` we are telling is `randomLetter = randomLetter + arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];` so if `randomLetter` doesn't have any value, the calculation cannot be done.... Did you get the idea?

Comment: @thesystem happy it helps you

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `document.write()`. Nowadays, you usually select an element, and then push the content into it. You can select an element by e.g. one of the following methods:

- `document.getElementById()`: selects an element by its ID, it is very fast
- `document.querySelector()`: selects an element by its CSS selector (not that fast, but good enough)

So here is an example:

```
var pw = 'password';
document.getElementById('pw').textContent = pw;
```

Or with the `querySelector`:

```
var pw = 'password';
document.querySelector('#pw').textContent = pw;
```

I've used `.textContent` on the node, because it prevents accidental HTML injection. If you explicitly want to allow HTML, you can also use `.innerHTML`.

---

And finally, here the complete example (including a button to execute the function):

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

function generate () {
    var password = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var randomLetter = arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];
        password += randomLetter;
    }
    document.getElementById("pw").textContent = password;
}

document.querySelector('#button-clicker').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    generate();
});
```

```html
<p id="pw"></p>
<button id="button-clicker">click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated your code please check. using id of you p tag you can place text on that. In you loop keep appending to randomLetter after looping just give it to innerHTML of your p tag `document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML = randomLetter;`

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
var randomLetter ='';
function generate () {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    randomLetter += arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];
  
  }
   document.getElementById("pw").innerHTML = randomLetter;
  randomLetter ='';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <button onclick="generate();">Generate password</button>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="pw">
    <!-- password should go here -->
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't clear the old password if you want to generate a different one. Place `randomLetter` within the function

Comment: @NewToJS updated now pls check

Comment: why down vote? any reason

Comment: I haven't down voted any answers. I have posted suggestions on how to make them work since most of the answers posted to this question have been incorrect/not working.

Comment: This would be better if what currently is called `randomLetter` would have a better name. That variable holds the _whole password_, not one random letter.

Comment: Do not use `innerHTML` if you don't want to add HTML.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is , Populate the content i.e Random Generated Password in Seprate HTML Body content , it can be Paragraph or Div, Use the java script code as :

```
document.getElementById('YOUR FIELD ID').innerHTML = "YOUR TEXT";
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this in your script tag.

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];

function generate () {
var randomLetter = "";
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    randomLetter += arr[Math.floor(arr.length * Math.random())];
  }
  
  var paraElem = document.getElementById("pw");
  var t = document.createTextNode(randomLetter);
  paraElem.appendChild(t)
}
```

Comment: @Xufox Bro its one text node for whole word. Its outside the loop

Comment: This would be better if what currently is called `randomLetter` would have a better name. That variable holds the _whole password_, not one random letter.

Comment: yup i m just helping him with his code.